# How to add text in video in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I checked [Movie Moments](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=3915d6e5-798e-4f87-a02f-d7fb305b6593) app of Windows Phone 8.1. It seems it's universal app as it's also available on Windows 8.1.

It has one feature to add captions in video. How can I add text in video in Windows Phone 8.1 app like that app? I checked whole WP 8.1 API it doesn't has any description regarding it. What approach can I use for it?

Comment: Are you sure it's modyfing video? Isn't it easier to put a TextBlock over MediaElement? (I haven't tried - just thinking)

Comment: Yes it's modifying it. You can share the video.

Comment: I'd suspect it's probably using DirectX to modify video frames (and C++).